# TextView to show two string variables on two lines

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to show two string variables, apple and banana inside a `TextView`. 
I have tried to add the newline character and doesn't work.  The only thing I haven't tried is to save the variables to files and read the files into the TextView.

Here is my java code:`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Button button;
    TextView tv;
    String apple = "bananas" + "\n";
    String banana = "apples" + "\n";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        activatebutton();
    }

    private void activatebutton() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // code here

                tv.setText(apple);
                tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                tv.setText(banana, null);
                tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the `Xml` code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
       android:background="#FFFF00"
       android:gravity="top"
       android:lines="10"
       android:maxLines="10"
       android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using setText twice, therefore erasing the previous text. You need to do setText(apple+banana), then your \n will work.

Comment: Could also use `append()` if there needs to be two separate calls

Comment: Thanks!  append() did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:

`tv.setText(apple);
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
tv.setText(banana, null);
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

by:

`tv.setText(apple + banana);
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void activatebutton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //First option
            //By this
            tv.setText(apple + banana);
            tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        }
    });
}
```

Or this, If you want to dynamically.

```
private void activatebutton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Second option
            //Or dynamically

            String oldText = tv.getText().toString();

            if(oldText.length > 0){
                tv.setText(oldText + "\n" + "your string here");
            } else {
                tv.setText("your string here");
            }   

            tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());            
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file Edit the EditText property as follows

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/two"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

In your MainActivity.java file

```
EditText editText;
String apple = "bananas" ;
String banana = "apples" ;
editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.setText(apple+"\n"+banana);
```

It is working well for me. I hope, it will help you.